# Related Rates Word Problem Help?

Tags: calculus

If two resistors with resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$ are connected in parallel then the total resistance $R$, measured in ohms, is given by $\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}$. If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are increasing at rates of o.3 ohms/second and 0.2 ohms/second, how fast is R changing when $R_1$=80 ohms and $R_2$=100 ohms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: You know $\dfrac{dR_1}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dR_1}{dt}$.

Differentiate your equation : $\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}$ with respect to $t$.

$\dfrac {dR}{dt}=d\frac{\dfrac{(R_1+R_2)}{R_1R_2}}{dt}$. You can get $\dfrac {dR}{dt}$

$d\dfrac{\frac{(R_1+R_2)}{R_1R_2}}{dt}= \dfrac{d}{dt}.\dfrac{(\dfrac{dR_1}{dt}+\dfrac{dR_2}{dt})-2(\dfrac{dR_1}{dt}.R_2+\dfrac{dR_2}{dt}.R_1)}{(R_1R_2)^2}$

Doesn't get more messier than this. ;).

Comment: yes  absolutely right.

Comment: I have no clue what is going on in this answer... :/

Comment: look,  first of all  you should  read basic calculus  rules,namely  you need to understand  what does  do derivative,in you case  $R_1,R_2$ are variable and derivative  each of  variables  and puting   values   corresponding  which you said already,gives you  rate of change,you should  read it,from calculus books

Comment: @bkaifos15: If I try to simplify each and every step it would get very messy. Try solving using basic rules of differentiation. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: @bkaifos15: Fine? Do you understand that?

Comment: It is less messy if you leave it $\frac d{dt}(\frac 1{R_1}+\frac 1{R_2})$ but you will get the same place.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Are we checking the 'Messy' rates with respect to my answer here? ;)

Comment: @dato-I'm a Veterinary Medicine BIOLOGY major...not a mathematician. Not everyone gets calculus even when we read it so please do not assume I haven't tried reading the rules. I want to medicate animals (which does not at all require calculus but basic math)...not do calculus problems the rest of my life. Thanks.

Comment: @Inceptio- yes thank you so much! :]

Comment: @bkaifos15: Pleasure ,sir.:)

Comment: @bkaifos15: And can I know where did you get this problem? I don't think resistors are used in Veterinary? Are they?

Comment: @inceptio It came from my calculus book and no resistors are not used but apparently I need calculus as a pre-req for calculus-based physics...

Answer (score 0):

simply calculate   $R$ for given  $R_1,R_2$;then increase $R_1,R_2$  by relevant  values and compare new result,generally they are constant right?if they are variables then express $R$ total as a  function of two variable and use  derivative

Answer (score 0):

This problem is straight-forward if you take it a step at a time.  You have the equation that relates $R_1$ and $R_2$, namely $\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$.  You know you want to differentiate that equation.  I recommend that you rewrite the fractions with negative exponents to make the differentiation more obvious.

$$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$$
$$R^{-1} = R_1^{-1}+R_2^{-1}$$

Now, differentiate with respect to time:

$$-1\cdot R^{-2}\frac{dR}{dt} = -1\cdot R_1^{-2}\frac{dR_1}{dt}+-1\cdot R_2^{-2}\frac{dR_2}{dt}$$
$$-R^{-2}\frac{dR}{dt} = -R_1^{-2}\frac{dR_1}{dt}+-R_2^{-2}\frac{dR_2}{dt}$$

Let's multiply through by -1 to get rid of all those negative terms:
$$R^{-2}\frac{dR}{dt} = R_1^{-2}\frac{dR_1}{dt}+R_2^{-2}\frac{dR_2}{dt}$$

It's probably easiest at this point to convert the negative exponents back to fractional form:

$$\frac{1}{R^2}\frac{dR}{dt} = \frac{1}{R_1^2}\frac{dR_1}{dt}+\frac{1}{R_2^2}\frac{dR_2}{dt}$$
$$\frac{\frac{dR}{dt}}{R^2} = \frac{\frac{dR_1}{dt}}{R_1^2}+\frac{\frac{dR_2}{dt}}{R_2^2}$$

Now, rearrange to solve for $\frac{dR}{dt}$ (multiply through by $R^2$):

$$\frac{dR}{dt} = R^{2}\left(\frac{\frac{dR_1}{dt}}{R_1^{2}}+\frac{\frac{dR_2}{dt}}{R_2^{2}}\right)$$

We were given the values of all of the variables except for $R$.  But we have the equation for $R$, viz., $\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$, so we can solve for $R$ (we know $R_1$ and $R_2$).

Plug in all of the known values.

There you go.  One other thing to note.  Read your problem carefully and be sure to use negative values for any rate of change that is decreasing.

#### Alternative Notation

Sometimes the notation can get in the way.  Though I find the above $\frac{dR}{dt}$ notation more generally useful, here is an alternative using $R^{'}$ notation that **differs only in the notation used** - the equations are otherwise **exactly the same**:

Rewrite using negative exponents:

$$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$$
$$R^{-1} = R_1^{-1}+R_2^{-1}$$

Now, differentiate with respect to time (*time* does not appear in the notation).  **Note**:  Instead of using $R^{'}$ as I do here, you could (more properly) use $R(t)^{'}$, but, in my view, that tends to defeat the whole purpose of simplifying the notation.

$$-1\cdot R^{-2}\cdot R^{'} = -1\cdot R_1^{-2}\cdot R_1^{'}+-1\cdot R_2^{-2}\cdot R_2^{'}$$
$$-R^{-2}\cdot R^{'} = -R_1^{-2}\cdot R_1^{'}+-R_2^{-2}\cdot R_2^{'}$$

Let's multiply through by -1 to get rid of all those negative terms:
$$R^{-2}\cdot R^{'} = R_1^{-2}\cdot R_1^{'}+R_2^{-2}\cdot R_2^{'}$$

It's probably easiest at this point to convert the negative exponents back to fractional form:

$$\frac{1}{R^2}\cdot R^{'} = \frac{1}{R_1^2}\cdot R_1^{'}+\frac{1}{R_2^2}\cdot R_2^{'}$$
$$\frac{R^{'}}{R^2} = \frac{R_1^{'}}{R_1^2}+\frac{R_2^{'}}{R_2^2}$$

Now, rearrange to solve for $R^{'}$:

$$R^{'} = R^{2}\left(\frac{R_1^{'}}{R_1^{2}}+\frac{R_2^{'}}{R_2^{2}}\right)$$

Find the value of $R$, as above, and substitute known values to solve.